# Loop and traversal in Python

Tags: python, traversal

I got a result from `BeautifulSoup`, but instead of printing all links, I want to print the first three links:

```
for link in links and i in range(3):
    print link
```

Which is not correct. What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just slice the list so you only get the first three elements:

```
for link in links[:3]:
    print link
```

Comment: Ah, you beat me. I hate the "at least 30 characters" rule :)

Comment: @gefei Yea, all these limits are rather annoying :p. I know exactly how you feel :)

Comment: Thank you :) , what if it is in Java?

Comment: @hln Java? I don't know any Java. This question was tagged for python :p

Comment: I know, I just wondered. I came from Java, but still don't know the solution

Comment: @hln Try searching for "list slicing in Java"

Answer (score 1):

you don't need a loop. simply `print links[:3]`.

EDIT. see also the comment of sberry

Comment: I think he wants to print each link one by one and not an actual list object

Comment: To be fair, you would likely want to `print "\n".join(links[:3])` to get the same output op was trying to get.